# How to do replace for all listbox items at once

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to make music name changer program for a purpose. But I have to replace all items in a listbox to use them in File.Move(). I tried someting but I think I need to get listbox items as a string to replace them.

```
   private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

I need the replace listbox items at once to use them in File.Move()

Comment: You might want to look into [`BindingList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Datasources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.datasource?view=netframework-4.8). Also, your question doesn't make much sense with your statement that you need to replace them at once to use them in `File.Move()`, what do you mean with that?

Comment: If this is WPF then you can simply assign a new collection to the `ListBox` that contains the modified names: `listBox2.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>(renamedItems);`

Comment: @Icepickle Good question...

Comment: @BionicCode I’m sorry what is the WPF

Comment: He is asking if you use Windows Presentation Foundation ([tag:wpf]) or Winforms (I was assuming [tag:winforms])

Comment: @Icepickle It’s windows forms

Comment: Then have a look at the links I added, they should at least give you some ideas how to make your list react to changes inside the list, without having you manipulate the listbox manually. As for why you need them for your `File.Move()` statement, please [edit] your question to make it more clear

Comment: @Icepickle The program is getting the full path of the musics inside the folder. I’ll replace the specific characters like - as a space example. And then I need the first path and the replaced path to use them in file.move()

Comment: As a preview for the actions that will happen? So you need 2 listboxes where the second listbox would show the potential new name? Maybe a listview is more a control you like, together with a typed class having OriginalName, SuggestedName properties? An then show both of them inside that listview for the user to validate (or correct) before executing the code?

Comment: @Icepickle Exactly. I have 2 listboxes for the old and new path

Comment: Then, have a look at the [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8) component. It will make your UI a lot more coherent (just columns in one control) or maybe even a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` (though I doubt you need the complexity or the power of inline editing)

Answer (score 0):

For everyone here is the correct code I made. It works really great.

```
  private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            list.Add(item.ToString());
            listBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString().Replace("_", " "));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a `list` variable there, why do you use `ToString()` twice? Why only replace in the `listBox2`. You seem to have tons of controls with `Control+Number` names, that won't make it easy for you in the future knowing what your control contains.